# Can I use "Excel Com object" on Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, excel, azure

I'm considering to implement "Accessing xlsx file form C#" on Azure Function. If I were in this situation, Can I use "Excel Com object" on Azure Functions? I'm not familiar about it. Do I have to use 3rd party module like as "Grape cigy"?

Comment: Short Answer - No.   In an Azure Function you do not have a real file system or user session context to run under.  The Office365 and SharePoint and Azure data ETL processes may be alternatives that you can look at.  You really want to get your architecture right when start going down this path.

Comment: I understood! Thanks!

Comment: I'll say that was a quick answer!